# Bessel processes and Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

In class, we talked about Bessel process as a process which solves the SDE:
$$
dB=\frac{n-1}{2B}dt+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{W_i}{B}dW_i
$$
Where $W_1,W_2,...,W_n$ are independent, standard Brownian motions.
We then showed that $B=||W||=(\sum_{i=1}^n(W_i)^2)^{1/2}$ solves this equation.
As a side note, the professor said that $X_t=\intop_0^t\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{W_i}{B}dW_i$ is a BM and that we can show it using Levy’s theorem.

I tried to prove that myself but got stuck at showing that $X_t^2-t$ is a martingale. Wherever I looked (books, lecture notes, or other questions here) it was like "you can easily see that $X_t$ is BM by Levy’s theorem". Well, turned out it's not that easy for me.

Can someone here please help me see that "easy" proof? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll show $X_t^2-t$ is a martingale. Note $X_t$ satisfies $dX_t=\sum_{i=1}^n\tfrac{W_i(t)}{B(t)}dW_i(t)$. Since the $W_i$ are independent $(dW_i)(dW_j)=\delta_{ij}dt$ where $\delta_{ij}$ is 1 if $i=j$ and 0 otherwise. It follows that
\begin{align*}
(dX_t)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \tfrac{W_i(t)^2}{B(t)^2}dt
\end{align*}
or, equivalently,
\begin{align*}
X_t^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n\int_0^t \tfrac{W_i(s)^2}{B(s)^2}ds = \int_0^t \sum_{i=1}^n\tfrac{W_i(s)^2}{B(s)^2}ds = t.
\end{align*}
The latter holds since $\sum_{i=1}^n\tfrac{W_i(s)^2}{B(s)^2}=1$ for all $s>0$ almost surely. Thus $X_t^2-t=0$ for all $t$ and so
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(X_t^2-t\vert\mathcal{F}_s) = 0 = X_s^2-s
\end{align*}
for any $s<t$. Here $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$ is the filtration generated by the Brownian motions. Since $X_t^2-t$ is also integrable for all $t$ (it is $0$) and adapted to $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$, it is a martingale.